# How to access req.body via expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, http-method

I cant access body when getting expressjs request

My main server.js file

```js
        app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(router);
```

My router.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const articlesContr = require("./../controllers/articlesContr.js");
const router = express.Router();

router
  .get("/articles", articlesContr.handleGet)
  .post("/articles", articlesContr.handlePost)
  .put("/articles", articlesContr.handleUpdate)
  .delete("/articles", articlesContr.handleDelete);
```

adminPanelContr.js

```js
const controller = {
    handleGet: (req, res) => {
        const query = req._parsedUrl.query;
        const parsedQuery = querystring.parse(query);
        // res.send(productsDb.getItem(parsedQuery));
        console.log(req)
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the value of req when you console log it?

Comment: @Kevin Yobeth, thanks for attention, it's not an undefined obj when I console log it, everythng there is like normally but body property is an empty object. body: {}

Comment: How exactly do you hit the endpoint? Did you use HTTP client such as Postman or a frontend application?

Comment: I'm using Postman for testing the requests. Specified there body as raw, json, {
    "item": { "name": "Sofia",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com" 
    }
}

Comment: GET requests have no `req.body` parameters. Be sure you hit this nodejs app with a POST or other request (not GET) to see a request body. And also check that your request carries a `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: woohoo now everyhing works! thanks! post this solution as answer, I'll mark it as a right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET requests don't have body parameters. Ordinarily `.get()` handler functions don't look for them.

If you use the same handler function for GET and other (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) requests, you need logic to avoid looking at the body when you get a GET.

When you send a request with a JSON body, don't forget to tell your server it's JSON by including a `Content-Type: application/json` HTTP header. That way you're sure express will invoke its `express.json` middleware to parse the body into the `req.body` object.

When you `.get()` a GET, you don't get a request body. There's gotta be some sort of doggerel poetry in there someplace.

If you use `res.json(object)` rather than `res.send(JSON.stringify(object))` express does a good job of setting the HTTP response headers to useful values for JSON.

And, I'm sure you know this:  Responding to a request with its own request body is a little strange.

Comment: yeah, it was just for check purposes, thanks again